# How to perform a calculation with conditionals in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I am trying to write a conditional where I want to get the average cost per visit in a new column. However, if the visit count is 0, then I want to use '1' instead so that the `Visit_cost` is not infinity.

My approach is throwing an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

df

```
id    Cost          Visit
2     52            1
3     85            0
4     853           10

df['VISIT_COST'] = [df['Cost']/df['Visit'] if df['Visit'] != 0 else df['Cost']/1]
```

final df:

```
id    Cost          Visit    VISIT_COST
2     52            1        52
3     85            0        85
4     853           10       85.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think best here is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), because very fast:

```
df['VISIT_COST'] = np.where(df['Visit'] != 0, df['Cost']/df['Visit'], df['Cost'])
print (df)
   id  Cost  Visit  VISIT_COST
0   2    52      1        52.0
1   3    85      0        85.0
2   4   853     10        85.3
```

Out of box solution - for replace `0` to `1` add boolean mask converted to integer:

```
df['VISIT_COST'] = df['Cost'].div(df['Visit'].eq(0).astype(int).add(df['Visit']))
print (df)
   id  Cost  Visit  VISIT_COST
0   2    52      1        52.0
1   3    85      0        85.0
2   4   853     10        85.3
```

Detail:

```
print (df['Visit'].eq(0).astype(int))
0    0
1    1
2    0
Name: Visit, dtype: int32

print (df['Visit'].eq(0).astype(int).add(df['Visit']))
0     1
1     1
2    10
Name: Visit, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

I think we should using `mask`

```
#df['VISIT_COST'] = np.where(df['Visit'] != 0,df['Cost']/df['Visit'] , df['Cost']/1)


df['VISIT_COST']=df.Cost.mask(df['Visit'] != 0,df['Cost']/df['Visit'])
```